# Intercept all queries on a model in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to intercept all queries that concern a model in SQLAlchemy, in a way that I can inspect it at the point where any of the query methods (`all()`, `one()`, `scalar()`, etc.) is executed.

I have thought about the following approaches:

## 1. Subclass the Query class

I could subclass `sqlalchemy.orm.Query` and override the execution code, starting basically from something like [this](http://derrickgilland.com/posts/demystifying-flask-sqlalchemy/).

However, I am writing a library that can be used in other SQLAlchemy applications, and thus the creation of the declarative base, let alone engines and sessions, is outside my scope.

Maybe I have missed something and it is possible to override the Query class for my models without knowledge of the session?

## 2. Use the before_execute Core Event

I have also thought of hooking into execution with the [before_execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.before_execute) event.

The problem is thatit is bound to an engine (see above). Also, I need to modify objects in the session, and I got the impression that I do not have access to a session from within this event.

---

What I want to be able to do is something like:

1. `session.query(MyModel).filter_by(foo="bar").all()` is executed.
2. Intercept that query and do something like storing the query in a log table within the same database (not literally that, but a set of different things that basically need the exact same functionality as this example operation)
3. Let the query execute like normal.

What I am trying to do in the end is inject items from another data store into the SQLAlchemy database on-the-fly upon querying. While this seems stupid - trust me, it might be less stupid than it sounds (or even more stupid) ;).

Comment: @Kosch As explained in the question, I do not hink I will have any luck with anything depending on a specific Engine or Session ☹.

Comment: @Kosch Yes, as you said: This event taps into the *engine* - which I cannot use, as explained in my question. My code is a library that defines a model and this interception code for an application that uses it, and that application defines creates the engine. I coul pass that to my library somehow, but then I still don't have access to a bound session within the event listener.

Comment: OK, obviously, I could derive a session from a new sessionmaker bound to the passed engine…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`before_compile`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.QueryEvents.before_compile) query event might be useful for you.

```
from weakref import WeakSet
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

visited_queries = WeakSet()

@event.listens_for(Query, 'before_compile')
def log_query(query):
    # You can get the session
    session = query.session

    # Prevent recursion if you want to compile the query to log it!
    if query not in visited_queries:
        visited_queries.add(query)
        # do something with query.statement
```

You can look at `query.column_descriptions` to see if your model is being queried.

Comment: Yep, that's it! Why I hadn't seen this event in the documentation is a mystery to me.

Comment: Improvement: I have used weakref.WeakSet() for visited_queries so queries that are only cached here, but not referenced by SQLAlchemy anymore, can be garbage-collected.